# YouCompleteMe and :bnext always lists the scratch buffer

Tags: vim

I am using YouCompleteMe for my C++ coding. It all works pretty fine, even in my not so easy to setup working environment. But every time I complete a method, it adds a new buffer in a window on the top to show me alternative functions with the same name. This buffer is the scratch buffer. When I am cycling through my buffers with `:bnext` and `:bprev` I am always cycling through that buffer. I can disable it with `:set nobuflisted`, but I don't want to do it manually every time I am in that file. How can I make this buffer not visible when cycling through the buffers? For some reason in vim-airline the *scratch buffer* is not shown in the list of open buffers.

I guess it can be solved with some *autocommand* in *.vimrc* but I have no Idea how to do that.

Comment: It's called *preview window*, you can read all about it in `:help preview-window`.

Comment: thank you. But I am not talking about the window, I am talking about the buffer in the preview window. And by reading the documentation about the preview-window I still have no idea how I can `set nobuflisted` in the buffer of the preview-window.

Comment: I can't try it now, but what about `autocmd BufEnter * if &previewwindow | setlocal nobuflisted | endif`?

Comment: is `&previewwindow` `true` even if I am not entering the _preview window_, but the _buffer_, that is also in the _preview window_? If I understand it correct, I would still enter the buffer once, but then it's set to nobuflisted?